# Executing code embedded in a string in Quarto or R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, quarto

I'm using an external JSON file to store the text that is being used in a Quarto document. This JSON file is being read in and then I'm using it to populate the text. I'd like to embed R code in the strings similar to what you can do with bare text in Quarto surrounded by tic marks.

Can this be done where the R code is executed

#### This is a JSON file being read in by Quarto (or R Markdown)

```js
{
  "about": {
    "title": "The mean is `r mean(1:5)`"
  }
}
```

#### Here is code in a Quarto (or R Markdown) document

````
```{r}
info <- jsonlite::read_json("report_text.json")
```

This works but I am not using the JSON: The mean is `r mean(1:5)`

This does not work, this is what I want to do: `r info$about$title`


```{r, results='asis'}
# This does not work either
cat(info$about$title)
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `knitr::knit_child` to parse chunks of text

````
```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
cat(knitr::knit_child(text=info$about$title, quiet=TRUE))
```
````

Comment: I like this one! Note, though, that the string, unlike the string in my example above, needs to be formatted between tic marks with a leading "r" -- ` `r mean(1:5)` `

Comment: @ZRoss I'm not sure I understand your comment. The example included in your question has the ticks and leading "r". This obeys the "regular" markdown formatting rules so it needs to be formatted in the same way as if it were included in the document itself.

Answer (score 0):

Techincally you could use `include` shortcode and temporary files.
Quarto:

````yaml
---
format: html
---
``` {r}
#| echo: FALSE

info <- jsonlite::read_json("report_text.json")
readr::write_file(info$about$title, "_info_about_title.qmd")
```

{{< include _info_about_title.qmd >}}
````

Comment: This is a clever idea that I had not thought about. I was hoping that there was a built-in way to tell the chunk to treat the string as if it were outside the chunk. Your approach probably works, but I probably prefer the approach I mention in my comment above where I just parse and re-assemble the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use eval and parse to get it to work, you will need to modify the json file though. if you make the input in json an entire r function string then you can use eval and parse to get the sentence to evaluate.

json file:

```
{
  "about": {
    "title": "paste0('The mean is ',  mean(1:5))"
  }
}
```

qmd:

````
---
title: "test"
format: html
editor: source
---

```{r}


info <- jsonlite::read_json("/Users/michael.curry/Documents/test.json")


```

This works `r eval(parse(text = info$about$title))`
````

Comment: Thanks for the response. That only works if the entire string is R code which doesn't really work here. I have already written a custom function to strsplit on tick marks and then reassemble the strings. This works, but is a bit of a pain!